# How to display "Add to Cart" Button when product price is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a plugin and need some help.

I want to Display Add To Cart Button on Single Product Page, even after if product price is empty in backed.

Any Proper Hook for It?

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
function item_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
$purchasable = true;
return $purchasable;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','item_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
```

code goes to function.php . (tested & work for empty price field)

Comment: Not Working , may be we need to set _regular_price = 0 ; when price is empty , if i insert Zero(0) in price field , add to cart button displaying how i update_post_meta with _regular_price = 0

Comment: @KrishanKaushik the answer has been edited. tested and work for empty price field.